How can I use netDXF to add dimension styles to a dxf?
I'm looking into netdxf (https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf/wiki) to try to add dimension styles to a dxf file. Can anyone help? I've added the NuGet package for it but am having trouble trying to resolve the following:

The entities which have that dimension style name are not updating. Is there a refresh dimensions call I need to perform before saving? Or change the current dimension style to the new one? The original dxf was saved with the dimensions labeled for the dimension style I'm trying to add but the dimension style was not added to the dimension styles table by the 3rd party software we use.

There are 3 dimension style properties I haven't been able to set properly. Can anyone help?



Primary Unit Tab: 'Apply to layout dimension Only' - how to set

Fit Tab: 'Annotative' - how to set

Text Style Tab: 'Fill color' - Setting a color does not work
=================================
private void AddDimensionStylesToDXF(string fileName)
{
          //Load the dxf
          netDxf.DxfDocument doc = netDxf.DxfDocument.Load(fileName);

          //Add a dimension style  
          netDxf.Tables.DimensionStyle style = new netDxf.Tables.DimensionStyle("Architectural-Tony");

          //Primary Units
          style.DimLengthUnits = netDxf.Units.LinearUnitType.Decimal;
          style.LengthPrecision = 6;
          style.FractionType = netDxf.Units.FractionFormatType.Horizontal;
          style.DecimalSeparator = ',';
          style.DimRoundoff = 0.5; //Round to 1/2"
          style.DimPrefix = "PP";
          style.DimSuffix = "SS";
          style.DimScaleLinear = 0.75;
          //For 'Apply to layout dimension only, must set dimscale/dimlfac to 0?
          style.SuppressLinearLeadingZeros = false;
          style.SuppressLinearTrailingZeros = false;

          //Lines
          style.DimLineColor = AciColor.Cyan;
          style.DimLineLineweight = Lineweight.ByBlock;
          style.ExtLineExtend = 0.25;
          style.ExtLineOffset = 0.5;
          style.ExtLine1Off = false;
          style.ExtLine2Off = false;
          style.ExtLineFixed = false;
          style.ExtLineFixedLength = 4;

          //Symbols and Arrows
          style.DimArrow1 = new netDxf.Blocks.Block("Box"); //Need to grab the arrow types (blocks) from somewhere (styleEntity.SymbolsArrowsStyles.FirstOrDefault()?)
          style.DimArrow2 = null;
          style.ArrowSize = 1;


          //Text Style
          style.TextFractionHeightScale = 1.5;
          style.TextHeight = 1.25;
          style.TextStyle = new netDxf.Tables.TextStyle("Basic", "simplex.shx");
          style.TextColor = AciColor.Blue;
          style.TextFillColor = AciColor.Green; //Set to null to specify no color. //COLORS DO NOT WORK
          style.TextVerticalPlacement = netDxf.Tables.DimensionStyleTextVerticalPlacement.Below;
          style.TextHorizontalPlacement = netDxf.Tables.DimensionStyleTextHorizontalPlacement.OverExtLine1;
          style.TextOffset = -1; //Displays a rectangular frame around the dimension text when negative values are used.

          //Fit
          style.FitOptions = netDxf.Tables.DimensionStyleFitOptions.BestFit;

          //Alternate Units
          style.AlternateUnits = new netDxf.Tables.DimensionStyleAlternateUnits();
          style.AlternateUnits.Enabled = true;
          style.AlternateUnits.LengthUnits = netDxf.Units.LinearUnitType.Decimal;
          style.AlternateUnits.LengthPrecision = 3;
          style.AlternateUnits.Multiplier = 2;
          style.AlternateUnits.Roundoff = 1;
          style.AlternateUnits.Prefix = "yyy";
          style.AlternateUnits.Suffix = "zzz";
          style.AlternateUnits.SuppressLinearLeadingZeros = false;
          style.AlternateUnits.SuppressLinearTrailingZeros = false;

          doc.DimensionStyles.Add(style);                               

          // Save the dxf
          bool result = doc.Save(fileName);

          if (result)
              MessageBox.Show("DXF successfully written.");

      }



